# PayPal API settings - what is wrong?

Tags: api, paypal, woocommerce

## Hi dears,

I would like to ask you, what is wrong.. I would like to set API in my wordpress e-shop, but I have problem with settings in PayPal administration... When I want to set it I cannot, because my window is clear.. I tried another browser, my mobile and on every place it is same...should I set something other on some another place?

thank you in advance
Zuzka
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83SWD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue at PayPal and the respective teams are working on this issue for resolution. Please file a ticket to PayPal MTS team at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/ for further updates on this issue.